# Is PHP under Apache reentrant?

Tags: php, lamp

Just a theoretical question really.

say my website consists of a form that uses the PHP mail functions to send e-mails. I have 500 users clicking submit at the same time. Now 500 e-mails in 500 different sessions have to be sent out from PHP.

will it be done concurrently? how many threads are involved? will each send block the others and do it one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you need to think about.

The first is how you have your web server configured.  If you're using Apache, there are a few [processing modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mpm.html) that can be picked from.  The most popular processing module is *prefork*, in which there is a single parent process and multiple child processes.  Each child handles one request at a time.  This avoids threading entirely, because not all Apache modules are thread safe.  You might also find the *worker* module somewhere in production.  It uses a combination of forking behavior and threading to serve multiple requests per child.  It can only be used when *every single Apache module and all of it's dependencies* are thread safe.

The second thing to think about is PHP itself.  While the core PHP language and some extensions are thread safe, many extensions *aren't* thread safe.  For this reason, when you're using Apache and mod_php, the prefork  processing module is your best choice.  (PHP itself has no internal concept of threads.)

**tl;dr:** Apache + PHP = one request per Apache child.  You'll usually only have 20-30 Apache children, meaning 20-30 possible concurrent requests.  This depends on configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In a linux-based server emails are sent using local `sendmail` command. This immedately accepts the message and returns. The rest of the work is done by your MTA (asynchronously) which is hardened and optimized thru decades to jobs such as this one.

Comment: much thanks. So perhaps the mail wasn't a good example. How about other actions, say, if the submit triggers a database request, or a local server-side calculation that takes, 10 seconds. Will some be done concurrently using X worker threads?

Comment: Apache will have simulateously many child processes running. There is maximum number of these processes defined by cofiguration. Each child process can start more threads (it is usually done at startup, and no threads are created runtime). - So it should not be a problem is a process pauses for a few seconds, but you should be aware of that when doing your configuration.

Comment: So when I write thread-free PHP code, I can assume that actions will be done concurrently as per the configuration on the Apache? I code with "single user" in mind?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use locks (which can typically make a thread pause) where it is needed you should write your php codes with the focus on a single user. (You don't need to do anything like `DoEvents` in VB.)